how to execute containers inside gem5?
I need to create and run containers (docker containers or lxc/lxd ones) inside gem5. Is there a way or workaround to do it ? I have checked the official documentation but this seems not possible.
I am trying to see if there is a way of running a container inside gem5. However, so far I did not find any resource on that.
